# how columns ordering in sql server database table impact performance?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, performance, performance-tuning

As I read about database design from logical model to physical databases, I noticed that the column ordering may need to be changed the sequence recorded in the logical data model. The DBMS is SQL Server.My question is how columns ordering in sql server database table  impact performance ?

Thank you so much for answering! I REALLY APPRECIATE IT.